# MySQL get all parents

Tags: mysql

We have orders and RMA's. RMA's can be created with order_products of an order. If in the RMA a new product is send, the product can also be added to a new RMA, and so on.

Now for example, I have this schematic structure of an order with RMA orders.

```
Order (1)
  |-> RMA (2)
    |-> RMA (3)
      |-> RMA (4)
        |-> RMA (5)
```

Now I want to traverse up from RMA (5), all the way up. So actually I want to get 5 records from the database containing all the RMA's and the original order (All from the `order` table). How can I do this, given the database structure shown below.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7c374/3).

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_rma_product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `order` (`id`, `type`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'order', 'Original order'),
    (2, 'rma', 'RMA of order 1'),
    (3, 'rma', 'RMA of order 2'),
    (4, 'rma', 'RMA of order 3'),
    (5, 'rma', 'RMA of order 4');

INSERT INTO `order_product` (`id`, `order_id`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Product'),
    (2, 2, 'Product'),
    (3, 3, 'Product'),
    (4, 4, 'Product');

INSERT INTO `order_rma_product` (`id`, `order_id`, `order_product_id`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 1, 'Return product'),
    (2, 3, 2, 'Return product'),
    (3, 4, 3, 'Return product'),
    (4, 5, 4, 'Return product');
```

I have tried this, but this give's me one row, so i tried contact_ws to get them all in on column. But this only works for the given set of JOINS, so not unlimited going up.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', op.order_id, op1.order_id, op2.order_id)
FROM `order` o
JOIN order_rma_product orp ON o.id = orp.order_id
JOIN order_product op ON orp.order_product_id = op.id

JOIN order_rma_product orp1 ON op.order_id = orp1.order_id
JOIN order_product op1 ON orp1.order_product_id = op1.id

JOIN order_rma_product orp2 ON op1.order_id = orp2.order_id
JOIN order_product op2 ON orp2.order_product_id = op2.id

WHERE o.id = '5';
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN not JOIN

Comment: @DanielE. True, but it is still limited to the number if LEFT JOINS I hardcode.